# Using Parboiled to parse different input types with same separator

Tags: scala, parboiled

I want to use Parboiled to parse a string that should turn a similar source into different types.

Specifically, I am trying to parse an input of words separated by the same separator into the equivalent of `(List[String], String)` where the last word is the second element of the tuple.

For example, `"a.bb.ccc.dd.e"` should be parsed to `(["a", "bb", "ccc", "dd"], "e")`.

A simplified version of my code is as follows:

```
case class Foo(s: String)

case class Bar(fs: List[Foo], f: Foo)

object FooBarParser extends Parser {

  val SEPARATOR = "."

  def letter: Rule0 = rule { "a" - "z" }

  def word: Rule1[String] = rule { oneOrMore(letter) ~> identity }

  def foo = rule { word ~~> Foo }

  def foos = rule { zeroOrMore(foo, separator = SEPARATOR) }

  def bar = foos ~ SEPARATOR ~ foo  ~~> Bar
}

object TestParser extends App {

  val source = "aaa.bbb.ccc"

  val parseResult = ReportingParseRunner(FooBarParser.bar).run(source)

  println(parseResult.result)
}
```

This prints `None` so clearly I am doing something wrong. Is Parboiled capable of parsing this?

Comment: Looks like your are using Parboiled1. You can use Parboiled2, it won't slove your problem, but.. You will gain a better tool.

Answer (score 0):

Please wrap all your rules inside 'rule' block. It helps in some cases